# Android how to add my application to "Accounts & sync" and how to use?

Tags: android, synchronization

In `Android` how to add my application to **Accounts & sync** and how to use it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/

this is an Accounts & sync example. worked this